# HTML Canvas - auto re-size as its content grows

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can i set an HTML5 canvas to auto re-size when the content inside it grows beyond its margins? I am developing a family tree application and  when a generation comes wider than the defined limits of the canvas, lines which connect nodes together disappear.

Comment: Prevailing answers are about re-size to fit to the window.

Comment: show the code for how youre drawing content to the canvas,,

Comment: he's want to resize based on the content drawn, not the windows size

Comment: I assume you give it at first a static width and height, use javascript to get these values and when you draw something on the canvas check to see if the coordinates of the drawing is past the margins, if it is just adjust the the width or height

Comment: @Pamblam, I am trying to extend the JsPedigree project. But the JS files are miniatured hence unable to read. anyway i'll put the link below . (Extremely new to JS and nothing at all :) ) Link: https://github.com/briantwhite/JavaCodeFromSVN/blob/master/jsPedigrees/war/jspedigrees/jspedigrees.nocache.js
and Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @ZetCoby, will give it a  try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With canvas there is no automatic features. It's a passive bitmap which you can use to draw graphics to, so all forms of logic need to be implemented "manually".

So in order to have it grow you will have to track positions and sizes of everything that is being drawn so you can calculate the total *bounding box* for the current graphics.

If the position + size of that bounding box exceed the canvas size, update the canvas size with that (canvas size = bounding box' position + size).

However, when resizing a canvas all current content as well as state(s) are lost so you will have to re-render and reinitialize the content as well as if was the first time drawing to it. This is something you need to plan for and incorporate into the design.

Answer (score 1):

Again, it really depends how you're drawing the content, but here is an example of how to do it when drawing an image to canvas..

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'someImaeg.png';
    base_image.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('canvas').width = base_image.width;
        document.getElementById('canvas').height = base_image.height;
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6y2qvd9/)